# Is there a software or framework to create Drag and Drop interfaces?

Tags: python, text-editor, json, editor, drag-drop

I want to create an interface that lets users interact with a big text-like file, but in a more visual way. Like editing a JSON file but with visual nodes and links instead of via text editor, similar to how "Drag and Drop programming" works in editors like Unreal Engine (see block #5 in image below).

It's fine whether it's free or not, but would like to ideally access it from a browser, although it's also fine if it needs to run locally as a desktop application.

Is there a software or language library/framework (Python, if possible) that can provide the basic building blocks to implement such a feature?

[image: Unreal Engine]